# How do I pass a Class as a parameter to a PHP function

Tags: php, laravel, class, static

I want to be able to pass a class (not an object of the class) to a PHP function. The desired end-result of all of this is the ability to call static functions present on that class. Take, for example:

```php
class MyClass extends Model
{
  public static function doThing()
  {
    return static::callOtherClassFunction();
  }
}
```

Now I have a function structured like this:

```php
function do_thing_with_any_class($class)
{
  return $class::doThing();
}
```

But, if I call `do_thing_with_any_class(MyClass::class)`, I get a syntax error.

Is what I want to do possible in PHP idiomatically? (i.e without using Reflection to get the static function).

P.S: This is tagged as 'Laravel' because 'MyClass' represents my 'Base Model' - the class that inherits directly from Laravel's "Model" class. But the question is definitely more general than that.

Comment: What PHP version are you on? Because passing `MyClass::class` works fine on PHP >= 5.5.0: https://3v4l.org/CNLUs (check the "eol versions" checkbox to test it in older versions of PHP) -- only on 5.4.45 and earlier does it throw a syntax error.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I'm on 7.4, and I tend to use Laravel Tinker (PsySH) to test things out. For whatever reason, it appears to fail inside PsySH but work in real code. I'm not sure what the difference would be, but you were absolutely right - it works beautifully. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the class itself as a parameter and a variable as the instance like so

```
function do_thing_with_any_class(MyClass $class)
{
  return $class::doThing();
}
```